# How to create image sub folders in python based on image labels

Tags: python, computer-vision, subdirectory

I need to create image subfolders based on it's labels,labels are stored in csv file example

`data\images`  (images folder continas all the images )

```
0.jpg,1.jpg,2.jpg......
```

`data\train.csv`   (`train.csv` folder contains image name & class )

```
train.head()

image_id     catergory

0              22

1             44

..             ...
```

i'm already tried this one

```
train_dir = r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Flower recognition\data\train'
train_sep_dir = r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Flower recognition\data\train\train_sep'
if not os.path.exists(train_sep_dir):
    os.mkdir(train_sep_dir)

for image_id, category in labels.values:
    # Create subdirectory with `class_name`
    if not os.path.exists(train_sep_dir + str(category)):
        os.mkdir(train_sep_dir + str(category)
    src_path = train_dir + image_id + '.jpg'
    dst_path = train_sep_dir + category + '/' + image_id + '.jpg'
    try:
        shutil.copy(src_path, dst_path)
    except IOError as e:
        print('Unable to copy file {} to {}'
              .format(src_path, dst_path))
    except:
        print('When try copy file {} to {}, unexpected error: {}'
              .format(src_path, dst_path, sys.exc_info()))
```

Comment: `os.makedirs(name)`

Comment: thank you for your response,but I need to store each image based on there label,how to do that

Comment: get label and use it - `os.makedirs(label)` and later `shutil.move("filename", label)` to move file to this folder.

Comment: hai furas , can u please share resource regarding that

Comment: @HEMANTHKUMARGADI give of an input and desired output

Comment: you forgot \  in all pathes - maybe use `os.path.join()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import shutil, os
import pandas as pd

labels = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
labels = labels.sort_values('Class')

class_names = list(labels.Class.unique())

train_images = '/train'
train_cat = '/train_'

#creating subfolders
for i in class_names:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join('train_', i))

#moving the image files to their respective categories
for c in class_names: # Category Name
    for i in list(labels[labels['Class']==c]['Image']): # Image Id
        get_image = os.path.join('train', i) # Path to Images 
        move_image_to_cat = shutil.move(get_image, 'train_/'+c)
```

'''
Image - image_id |
Class - category
'''